# jQuery onclick create and append element with attributes and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with many `anchors` pointing to different video files and one `div`:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/example-1.mp4" class="video">1</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/example-2.mp4" class="video">2</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/example-3.mp4" class="video">3</a>

<div id="video-player">

</div>
```

When the user clicks a link, I want a `video` element to be created inside the `div`, like so:

```
<div id="video-player">
    <video>
        <source src="[HREF-FROM-THE-A]">
    </video>
</div>
```

I need `controls` and `autoplay` attributes on the `video` element.

Do I need to add a class to my anchors? I'm thinking so... because I have other links on the page that aren't videos. Updated question.

This should be easy for someone, I'm terrible with JS/jquery. I tried searching: "jquery create element onclick", "jquery append element onclick".

Comment: Take a look into `.data()` and data-* attributes :) also don't use inline js - its bad practice that leads to hard to maintain code

Comment: Isac's answer is fine, but this sounds like a good use-case for the html5 [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element and [`shadow-dom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM), which lets you keep the html structure out of the javascript code.

Comment: Just an idea, wouldn't it be a cleaner implementation if you kept the video tags in the base HTML, and simply replaced the video source through jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the clicks on the `<a>` and use the `html` method to inject the video tag you need. The `href` value can be fetched using jquery's `attr` method, combined with `$(this)` to be of the clicked `<a>`:

```js
$("a.video").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#video-player").html("<video controls src=" + $(this).attr("href") + "></video>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.example.com/example-1.mp4">1</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/example-2.mp4">2</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/example-3.mp4">3</a>

<div id="video-player">

</div>
```

I've also added `controls` on the generated `<video>` so that it is clearer that its being created.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your anchor tags with :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="video" onclick="addvideo('http://www.example.com/example-1.mp4')">1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="video" onclick="addvideo('http://www.example.com/example-2.mp4')">2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="video" onclick="addvideo('http://www.example.com/example-3.mp4')">3</a>
```

and then add a javascript function :

```
function addvideo(href)
{
    $('#video-player').html('<video controls autoplay><source src="'+href+'"></video>');
}
```